# Why is the ICAO prefix for Alaskan airports "P"?

Tags: airport

Mainland US airports all (to the best of my knowledge) have ICAO codes beginning with "K", however Alaskan airports all (from a couple of minutes rummaging about on [FlightRadar24](https://flightradar24.com) and [Flight Aware](https://flightaware.com)) seem to be prefixed with "P"?

Additional searching seems to indicate that Hawaiian airports are also prefixed with "P".

Comment: The airports in Guam, a U.S. territory also start with P. My understanding is that the K designates airports in the contiguous states of the U.S.  U.S. airports in the Pacific take the P designation, those in the Atlantic (Puerto Rico) the T designation. A further delineation is that Alaska airports are PA, Hawaii airports PH, Guam airports PG, Puerto Rico airports PJ.

Comment: @Terry TJxx for Puerto Rico.

Comment: Sounds like you've got the makings of an answer there, @Terry...

Comment: Yeah, close enough to be a dupe, @RalphJ. That's what I get for not doing much searching...

Comment: @RalphJ Thanks for catching that. A typo on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Definition from wikipedia:

The ICAO (/ˌaɪˌkeɪˈoʊ/, eye-KAY-oh) airport code or location indicator is a four-letter code designating aerodromes around the world. These codes are defined by the International Civil Aviation Organization, and published in ICAO Document 7910: Location Indicators are used by air traffic control and airline operations such as flight planning.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/ICAO_FirstLetter.svg/1200px-ICAO_FirstLetter.svg.png

This is a map of every ICAO airport code wordwide.

Alaska has PA, PF, PO and PP as airport codes. P = Eastern North Pacific.
PA=USA (Alaska) (also PF, PO and PP)

There is no special meaning behind the letter P and these codes, it's just a classification!!